# unable to send high resolution photo via send_photo method of Telgram bot API

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-api

Using telegram bot api in python, I am sending photo using a file.

1. First I get the photo from a url.
2. Save the photo to disk. (Full Resolution)
3. Read the file and pass it to `bot.send_photo`
4. Get the `file_id` contained in returned `Message` object and save it.
5. Next time I send via `file_id` upon new /command.

First request:

> ```
> file = open(get_filename(), 'rb')  
> msg = context.bot.send_photo(chat_id, file, caption=None)  
> fileid = msg.photo[len(msg.photo)-1].file_id
> ```

Second and onwards ...

> ```
> context.bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=get_fileid(), caption=None)
> context.bot.send_message(chat_id, text=EXPLANATION)
> ```

Here file ID represent the highest resolution file id available in [PhotoSize](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize) array.

[image]

Here is the file id: `AgACAgQAAxkDAAIBMmAK636SiNEGCA8UILZ55gVppXfqAAIytjEbqp1RUJwNFOjmz7N6ZoHuJ10AAwEAAwIAA3cAAwRjBAABHgQ`

**Problem**: I am receiving 1k resolution photo in bot chat. Please advise what I am missing here.